# Detect which soft-keyboard key is pressed using dtmf in android

Tags: android

How to get key pressed by customer using soft keyboard from their mobile to our mobile using DTMF in android?

I want to build Mobile application Android like customer support. So for that I want to get their mobile number on receiving call of customer and play some instructions e.g For English press one and After that I want to receive that pressed by user in my application. how can I do that.

I have tried a code from GitHub but not work for me.

Comment: For clarity: do you mean you're trying to write a "customer support app" for an Android phone? That is, a customer dials a support number (using a mobile, land-line, whatever) and you want your app (running on your phone) to answer the call, play messages, and interpret any DTMF tones their phone might generate?

Comment: Yes I want to build same as like.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't know that it _isn't_ possible, but a couple of Q&As on here suggest it either _wasn't_ possible, or at least there wasn't any built-in way of doing so: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35279856/2096401) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56207669/2096401).

Comment: Is there any other solution for this or any external API or library required?